# find all ideals of quotient ring $Q[x]/I$

Tags: maximal-and-prime-ideals, quotient-group

find all ideals of quotient ring $Q[x]/I$ where $I = Q[x]f(x)$, $f(x) = x^3 + 4x^2-9x-36$.

should I first factor the $f(x)$? 
Are those Factors of $f(x)$ the ideal of $Q[x]/I$?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, factor $f(x)$ and then use the correspondence theorem, which tells you that ideals of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I$ are all of the form $J/I$, where $J$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ containing $I$.

Comment: Hi, I end up with f(x) = (x + 4) (x - 3) (x + 3), but in term of Q[x], what would the ideals be?

Comment: If $p(x)$ divides $f(x)$, then the ideal $\mathbb{Q}[x]f(x)$ is contained in the ideal $\mathbb{Q}[x]p(x)$

Comment: ok,thanks a lot